# JOOQ Log4j - missing console output

Tags: java, log4j, ivy, slf4j, jooq

I have a problem with logging as it is described [here](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.2/manual/sql-execution/logging/).

My code:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);

Settings settings = new Settings();
settings.withRenderFormatted(true);
settings.setExecuteLogging(true);

DSLContext dslContext = DSL.using(conn, SQLDialect.MYSQL,  settings);


dslContext.select(USER.USERID, USER.IMIE, USER.NAZWISKO).from(USER).orderBy(USER.USERID).limit(1, 2).fetch();
```

**And I have nothing in my console**

This is my log4j.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<log4j:configuration>
    <appender name="stdout" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <priority value="debug" />
        <appender-ref ref="stdout" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

and my IVY dependencies:

```
<dependency org="org.jooq" name="jooq" rev="3.2.2"/>
<dependency org="org.jooq" name="jooq-codegen" rev="3.2.2"/>
<dependency org="org.jooq" name="jooq-meta" rev="3.2.2"/>

<dependency org="mysql" name="mysql-connector-java" rev="5.1.26"/>
<dependency org="log4j" name="log4j" rev="1.2.16"/>
<dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-simple" rev="1.7.4"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I could read the code (`cf org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger`), `Jooq` is guessing the logger to use by trying to load each ones until it succeeds. Considering you ivy.xml, you have both `Log4j` and `slf4j-simple`. And Jooq is trying `slf4j` first. So `Log4j` is not used.

So you need to remove `slf4j-simple` from your dependencies.

If you do require a `slf4j logger,` try `slf4j-log4j12`, which redirects `slf4j` logs into log4j.

Comment: Ah, nice catch! It actually hadn't occurred to me that an slf4j dependency was also added...

Comment: Seems to work better since jooq 3.12.0: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7643

Answer (score 1):

Nicolas, You are the Boss : ) and You were right

this is proper dependencies,on IVY:

```
<dependency org="org.jooq" name="jooq" rev="3.2.2"/>
<dependency org="org.jooq" name="jooq-codegen" rev="3.2.2"/>
<dependency org="org.jooq" name="jooq-meta" rev="3.2.2"/>

<dependency org="mysql" name="mysql-connector-java" rev="5.1.26"/>
<dependency org="log4j" name="log4j" rev="1.2.16"/>
<dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-log4j12" rev="1.7.5"/>
```